# Saber la posición de los items MySql

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

Tengo esta `query`

```
SELECT nombre
     , puntos
  FROM ( SELECT t.*
              , @pos:=@pos+1 pos
              , if( nombre = 'MiNombre', @ref:=@pos, null )
           FROM ( SELECT nombre, puntos
                    FROM usuarios
                    WHERE tipo = 'false'
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT nombre, puntos
                    FROM usuarios2
                    WHERE activo = 'true'
                   ORDER BY puntos desc, nombre
                ) t
              JOIN ( SELECT @pos:=0, @ref:=null ) v
        ) t2
  WHERE pos between @ref-3 and @ref+3
```

Lo que hago en ella es juntar 2 tablas `usuarios` y `usuarios2` luego las ordeno por `puntos` y obtengo el `item` con *MiNombre*, tres menos y tres más, hasta aquí todo bien.

Lo que busco y no se me ocurre como hacer es añadir una columna llamada `posicion` y obtener ahí la posición en la que está cada `item`.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Edito con más información

tabla `usuarios`

```
nombre  | puntos | tipo 
________________________
nombre1 | 9999   | false
nombre2 | 9999   | false
MiNombre| 5000   | false
nombre3 | 2000   | false
nombre60| 1000   | false
```

tabla `usuarios2`

```
nombre  | puntos | activo 
_________________________
nombre15 | 9999   | true
nombre26 | 9999   | true
nombre30 | 4000   | true
nombre32 | 2000   | true
nombre50 | 1500   | true
```

Mi `query` une ambas tablas, luego ordena por `puntos` y `nombre` de manera `DESC`, busca `MiNombre` y además tres más arriba y tres más abajo (si es que hay arriba y abajo) y obtengo lo siguiente

```
nombre  | puntos  
_________________
nombre2  | 9999   
nombre15 | 9999  
nombre26 | 9999 
MiNombre | 5000  
nombre30 | 4000 
nombre3  | 2000 
nombre32 | 2000
```

Hasta ahí todo funciona bien, pero quiero saber es en que posición está cada uno de esos 6 cuando ya están ordenados, así sería el resultado

```
nombre  | puntos  | posicion
_____________________________
nombre2  | 9999   |    2
nombre15 | 9999   |    3
nombre26 | 9999   |    4
MiNombre | 5000   |    5
nombre30 | 4000   |    6
nombre3  | 2000   |    7
nombre32 | 2000   |    8
```

Algo así como si fuese una clasificación y quisiera saber mi posición, los 3 de arriba mía y los 3 de abajo mía y luego saber en que posición hemos quedado cada uno de los 6.

Comment: Esta consulta de cabeza es complicada, pásanos algún dato de muestra y el resultado que esperas para esos datos

Comment: @DavidJP he añadido más información, espero que sirva, gracias!

Comment: ¿Intentaste agregar `pos` al `SELECT`?

Comment: @Sal simplemente tenía que hacer lo que dices, demasiado fácil y lo que me estaba yo complicando.. Gracias! Si lo pones como respuesta la marco como solución.

Answer (score 0):

Haces un `JOIN` intermedio que no consigo entender muy bien, pero el caso es que así te funcionará:

```
SELECT nombre,puntos,pos FROM (
    SELECT nombre,puntos,@pos:=IFNULL(@pos+1,0) pos,
      IF( nombre = 'MiNombre', @ref:=@pos, null )
      FROM (
        SELECT *
          FROM usuarios
          WHERE tipo=FALSE
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM usuarios2
          WHERE activo=TRUE
        ORDER BY puntos DESC,nombre  
      ) c1  
  ) c2 WHERE pos BETWEEN @ref-3 AND @ref+3;
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios para completar la respuesta.

**Dataset**

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios (
  nombre varchar(15),
  puntos int,
  tipo bool
);
CREATE TABLE usuarios2 (
  nombre varchar(15),
  puntos int,
  activo bool
);
INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES
('nombre1',9999,0),('nombre2',9999,0),
('MiNombre',5000,0),('nombre3',2000,0),
('nombre60',1000,0);
INSERT INTO usuarios2 VALUES
('nombre15',9999,1),('nombre26',9999,1),
('nombre30',4000,1),('nombre32',2000,1),
('nombre50',1500,1);
```

**Resultado**

```
+----------+--------+-----+
| nombre   | puntos | pos |
+----------+--------+-----+
| nombre15 |   9999 |   2 |
| nombre2  |   9999 |   3 |
| nombre26 |   9999 |   4 |
| MiNombre |   5000 |   5 |
| nombre30 |   4000 |   6 |
| nombre3  |   2000 |   7 |
| nombre32 |   2000 |   8 |
+----------+--------+-----+
```

Comment: Hola! gracias por su ayuda, he probado la query pero no me da el resultado que se supone que deberia dar, me da la lista completa de participantes ordenada por puntos, no solo las 6 posiciones que busco, y la columna pos todos con el valor 0

Comment: Ejecútala 2 veces o añade un `SET @pos=0;` antes del `SELECT` y ejecuta las dos queries juntas

Comment: podrías mostrarme como hacerlo? no tengo mucha idea de hacer query

Comment: Sí, claro. Contacta conmigo a través de mi perfil en LinkedIn y te lo explico en una videollamada compartiendo la pantalla :)